# How to launch intent ACTION_TIME_TICK for every second?

Tags: java, android, time, android-intent

Hi i would like to know how to use the intent ACTION_TIME_TICK for every second rather than for every minute?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with [ACTION_TIME_TICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK), if you read the docs its sent every minute.